# sortedArrayUsingDescriptors method

Tags: arrays, sorting, using, descriptor

I have a questen about sorting an array.

after which method does `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` work?
bubblesort or quicksort or so on?
or is it another algorithm?
can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

here s a quick example:

```
NSSortDescriptor *country = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"country" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *city = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"city" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorted = [bag sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: country, city, nil]];
```

1. The NSSortDescriptor API does not specify the algorithm (or even, like virtually all of the Cocoa APIs, a Big-O complexity guarantee). You should assume that the sort algorithm used is an implementation detail. You should probably also assume, however, that the algorithm used is selected at run time for best performance. Unless you have hard requirements for time or memory complexity, you should use the public API and let the framework authors at Apple worry abou the details.
2. If you have complexity requirements, you may find CHDataStructures framework helpful in writing your own collection/sorting implementation.

Comment: so it depends on the situation which algorithm is choosen?